# Memory Managing C

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I wrote a function, using the C header `stdio.h` that returns content of a file (text or html). Can anyone please go through it and suggest if I have done the memory management efficiently. I shall be so pleased to hear better suggestions that I can improve my codes.

```
char *getFileContent(const char *filePath)
{   
//Prepare read file
FILE *pReadFile;
long bufferReadSize;
char *bufferReadFileHtml;
size_t readFileSize;
char readFilePath[50];
sprintf_s(readFilePath, "%s", filePath);
pReadFile = fopen (readFilePath, "rb");

if (pReadFile != NULL)
{
    // Get file size.
    fseek (pReadFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    bufferReadSize = ftell (pReadFile);
    rewind (pReadFile);

    // Allocate RAM to contain the whole file:
    bufferReadFileHtml = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * bufferReadSize);

    if (bufferReadFileHtml != NULL) 
    {
        // Copy the file into the buffer:
        readFileSize = fread (bufferReadFileHtml, sizeof(char), bufferReadSize, pReadFile);

        if (readFileSize == bufferReadSize) 
        {
            return bufferReadFileHtml;
        } else {
            char errorBuffer[50];
            sprintf_s(errorBuffer, "Error! Buffer overflow for file: %s", readFilePath);
        }
    } else {
        char errorBuffer[50];
        sprintf_s(errorBuffer, "Error! Insufficient RAM for file: %s", readFilePath);
    }

    fclose (pReadFile);
    free (bufferReadFileHtml);
} else {
    char errorBuffer[50];
    sprintf_s(errorBuffer, "Error! Unable to open file: %s", readFilePath);
}
}
```

Comment: You could improve your code by removing the possible undefined behaviour from not returning something in all cases.

Comment: c ***XOR*** C++? They are two different languages.

Comment: In three places you define an `errorBuffer` array in a nested scope, `sprintf_s()` some text into it, do nothing with the content, and then immediately leave the scope. That seems pointless.

Comment: SO is not a site for code review, but for questions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a C program, not a C++ program. While it *will* compile using most C++ compilers, it doesn't take advantage of any C++ features (e.g. new/new[], delete/delete[], explicit casting, stream operators, strings, nullptr etc.)

Your code almost looks like a safe C function, although I think `sprintf_s` is a Microsoft-only function, and thus probably won't compile using GCC, Clang, Intel, etc. as it isn't a part of the standard.

Your function should also return a value at all times. Turn compiler warnings on to catch these kinds of things; they make debugging a lot easier :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could make your function void, since you don't return anything anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually this function is just one function called by many other functions in the same program. This function returns the content of the file it has read using the following code:

`if (readFileSize == bufferReadSize) 
{
   return bufferReadFileHtml;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to be said without knowing how you will be using the buffer you've created.  Here are some possible considerations:

1) When you are reading the file into a buffer, your processor is doing nothing else for this program.  It might be better to read and begin analyzing the already read portion in parallel.

2) If you need really fast-efficient-low memory file IO, consider converting your program to a state machine and forget about the buffer altogether.

3) If you don't really have a very demanding application, you are killing yourself by writing in C.  C#, python, etc-- almost any other language has better string manipulation libraries.

Btw, you should use snprintf for portability and safety, as others have pointed out.